# Ways to measure similarities/congruence of tracks (point features) in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, gps, arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics

I have a sets of GPS coordinates recorded while tracking different cross country runners. What I would like to do is to compare how similar the tracks of the individual runners are.

Is there a test for congruence or some such in ArcGIS 10?

Comment: It would help to make your sense of "similarity" more precise. For instance, does speed matter or do you care only about the paths followed? For a very closely related question--which provides some answers to yours--please see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49923/how-do-i-compare-two-maps-to-determine-which-is-better.

Comment: What do you mean by "Similar"? Miles per week run? Time of day trained? Total Elevation run? Or the same physical run (street, trail, etc) in common?

Comment: probably just interested in the path, you may want to have a nominal track to which to compare the individual tracks

Comment: Antonio is right, I'm primarily interested in similarities of the paths. What I want to analyse is to which extend the runners' course decisions are random or influenced by topographical features. If the courses were completely random the paths would be all over the place. But they aren't. Even though the runners all ran independently (on different days), some of them seemed to make the same decisions with regard to the course the followed. I want to get a measure that allows it to determine which paths are similar to each other.

Comment: Do you have a DEM?  This would especially be interesting from orienteering competition.

Comment: To progress this question can you [edit] it to include your clarifications and anything else that may make it clearer to potential answerers, please?