# Quantifying polyline overlap

Tags: arcgis-10.1, spatial-statistics, line, borders

I have a set of regions and would like to quantify the degree to which the boundary of these regions are situated on/near rivers. I have turned the regions from polygons to polylines in arcgis 10.1 and have the rivers as polylines.

Is there any way to quantify what percentage of the boundaries fall on rivers, and therefore statistically show the degree of overlap between these two vector features?

Comment: A closely related question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49923 may suggest some useful approaches.

Comment: As polygon on polygon this would be easy (see union, intersect, identity) but as line on line that's a bit more complex. The intersection of a line on line is a point and it would be hard to say this as a percentage of a line as a point has no length. If you wanted to know how much of the boundary polygon is within a distance of a river then this would be easier - just buffer the rivers then union! If this is not the case can you please elaborate further.